Firebase firestore throw QuotaExceededError on 'Blaze plan'
Log like this.

@firebase/firestore: Firestore (9.9.3): AsyncQueue Failed to persist write: QuotaExceededError: Failed to execute 'setItem' on 'Storage': Setting the value of 'firestore_mutations_firestore/[DEFAULT]/(project_name)/_88' exceeded the quota.

This symptom is only occurring in Edge. How can I solve this problem?
I attempted to batch write, and expected to be successful. I checked the payment issue, but there was no problem. also I have never set any quotas this project. It's fine in Chrome and Firefox.

https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/firestore.googleapis.com/quotas?
